# paster quickstart not an option

Tags: python, windows-7, turbogears2, paster

I am just installing TurboGears2 on Windows 7 running a virtual environment (python 2.7). I am not seeing the paster quickstart option when I run

```
paster --help
```

Instead, here's that output:

```
(VirtualEnv_1) C:\VirtualEnv_1\Scripts>paster --help
Usage: paster-script.py [paster_options] COMMAND [command_options]

Options:
  --version         show program's version number and exit
  --plugin=PLUGINS  Add a plugin to the list of commands (plugins are Egg
                    specs; will also require() the Egg)
-h, --help        Show this help message

Commands:
 create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
 help         Display help
 make-config  Install a package and create a fresh config file/directory
 points       Show information about entry points
 post         Run a request for the described application
 request      Run a request for the described application
 serve        Serve the described application
 setup-app    Setup an application, given a config file

TurboGears2:
 tginfo       Show TurboGears 2 related projects and their versions
```

So, it's no surprise that when I run :

```
(VirtualEnv_1) C:\VirtualEnv_1\Scripts>paster quickstart
```

I get:

```
Command 'quickstart' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
  exe          Run #! executable files
  help         Display help
  make-config  Install a package and create a fresh config file/directory
  points       Show information about entry points
  post         Run a request for the described application
  request      Run a request for the described application
  serve        Serve the described application
  setup-app    Setup an application, given a config file
  tginfo       Show TurboGears 2 related projects and their versions
```

My questions: Why is it missing, and how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get into this situation when you've installed the package required to *run* a TurboGears app (`TurboGears2`), but not the one required to *develop* a TurboGears app (`tg.devtools`).

Running the following command while in your virtualenv should install the correct package:

```
easy_install -i http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/downloads/current/index tg.devtools
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Why this isn't more apparent on their documentation is a crime against humankind :)